# How to make private and public user's fields in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to give public and private options for fields to user.
Suppose, I want to make private to "Birth Date" field, it should not be appeared on detail page for other user.

I have my customized registration controller in devise. Fields are saving ,updating and showing but I don't know how hide private fields for other users.
I am really confused how to start????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a method e.g. `current_user` (current logged in user, if you use e.g. devise) then you can do something like

`<%= @user.birth_date if @user == current_user %>`

Comment: good point. Or maybe you can have different views for self profile or other's profile - and let the controller to choose.